# Integrated webcam suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, webcam, lenovo-vantage

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T580 whose integrated webcam suddenly stopped working, i.e. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNA15.png) image pops up whenever I try to use it in any application (like Camera, Skype, Zoom etc.). Also the green LED that usually signals that the webcam is being used does not turn on anymore.

I suspected a driver issue, so I went to Driver Manager and tried update/rollback/uninstall+reinstall driver. Nothing worked. Then I read on the internet that the webcam could have been turned off or that the privacy mode could have been turned on in the Lenovo Vintage app. I checked and everything is as it should: camera is on, privacy mode is off.

I also tried installing all driver and Windows updates through the Vantage app. No result. I never encountered such a issue before (usually reinstalling the driver fixes things). So I would greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You didn't disable it via its function key?

Comment: No. I don't even have a function key that can disable the webcam.

Comment: The "thinkshutter" is open?

Comment: Gerard: that was it. Thank you! Just as an explanation: it's not actually my computer. It belongs to my mother and I don't have hardware access to it (just TeamViewer). I did not know it had a shutter and she said it doesn't when I asked first time. This time I insisted and she found it. Quite embarrassing :)

Comment: Not at all, and I feel your pain, having myself once given a laptop to my mother.  But that was with Linux, not Microsoft, and so I have a lot less maintenance.  Mind if I post the thinkshutter as an answer?

Comment: No. Please post it and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the planet's forests from being converted into post-its, Lenovo invented the "Thinkshutter", so that hackers can be prevented from watching you using your own webcam.  The inventor perhaps did not realize this name could have other meanings.  Anyway, when it's shut, the webcam is disabled, Windows considers it's no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Windows Privacy settings (not Lenovo's), shown below?

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `privac` and select *Privacy* settings.
2. Click on *Camera*.
3. If, "Camera access for this device is off," change it. *If that cannot be changed, there may be a *Group Policy* preventing that which you'll need to fix.
4. If Windows *apps* need to access the camera, turn on that setting.
5. Select specific *apps* to enable camera use.

[image: Camera Privacy Settings]

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! Everything is fine in this menu too.

Answer (score 0):

> I checked and everything is as it should: camera is on, privacy mode
> is off.

Look in Device Manager under Camera. If not there or a Red or Yello, X then the Camera has a hardware error and needs to be replaced.

If the camera exists in Device Manager, try running DISM and SFC.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Download the Driver from the Lenovo Support site for your specific Model of ThinkPad.

Now see if it installs.

Comment: I already checked the Camera in Device Manager because, as I said, I already tried updating/reinstalling the driver. It explicitly says that "This device is working properly".

Comment: I posted steps for DISM and for getting a new driver.